# Jpeg image not displayed in Qt4.8.5 deployed visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qml, qimage, qt4.8

When I am using Qt Creator from Qt 4.8.5, jpeg image is displayed properly. However, this same code deployed to Visual Studio 2008 with Qt 4.8.5 does not display my jpeg image. What would be issue? May I need to add `qjpegd4.dll` or Macro to setup the project dependencies?

```
Image {
     fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
     smooth: true
     source: "../components/images/success.jpg"
     sourceSize.width: 60
     sourceSize.height: 50
}
```

Comment: how to set dynamic library in visual studio for jpeg supported dll?

Comment: The source path is relative.. make sure the working directory of your Visual Studio project is set properly, or use an absolute path.